# MFC: Show or minimize (to hide) window on startup

Tags: winapi, mfc, showwindow

In `CWinApp::InitInstance()` I have:

```
if (!ProcessShellCommand(cmdInfo))
  return FALSE;
m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(m_MinimizeOnStartup ? SW_SHOWMINIMIZED : SW_SHOWNORMAL);
m_pMainWnd->UpdateWindow();
```

But my ShowWindow call is not resulting in an `OnSize()` or `OnShowWindow()` callback?  During the `ProcessShellCommand()` those are called a few times as the first `OnShowWindow()` restores the window size when last shutdown via `SetWindowPlacement()`.  That all works good, restoring to last state, but `ProcessShellCommand()` afterwards calls `ShowWindow` with `SW_SHOW` which causes a my hidden when minimized window to show on the taskbar.   Where is the proper place to either show the window or minimize it (to hide it).   Basically what happens is the minimize comes in (on `SetWindowPlacement()`, window is hidden, `MFC` later calls `SW_SHOW` which makes it minimized on the taskbar instead of hidden, my forced `ShowWindow()` doesn't do anything.

TIA!!

Comment: So it appears when already minimized it doesn't send it if request minimize.

Comment: In Win32 C++ application, I can receive [`WM_SIZE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-size) message even if I set `SW_SHOWMINIMIZED` via [`ShowWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow)function after the window create like this: `ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED);` But you can't receive corresponding [`OnSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=vs-2019#onsize) call of MFC, is this your issue right?

Comment: yes, there was no OnSize nor OnShowWindow when it was already in that state.  I found I could set `m_nCmdShow=SW_HIDE` in the `CAppWnd` and then later I would do the `SetWindowPlacement()` and let it do its thing.  However, that function sends a `SIZE_RESTORED` prior to `SIZE_MINIMIZED` when using `wp->showCmd=SW_SHOWMINIMIZED;` so you get a flash of the window before it goes away (since my OnSize will `ShowWindow(SW_SHOW)` on `SIZE_RESTORED` if hidden).   Not sure if a trick to get around that?

Comment: I took out my `ShowWindow(SW_SHOW)` on `SIZE_RESTORED` when not visible and it still ended up showing the window and now without the flash.  So I'm good now!

Comment: If the issue solved you can post an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no OnSize() nor OnShowWindow() callback on ShowWindow() when already in those states.    Set `m_nCmdShow=SW_HIDE` in `CAppWnd` then at the end of the `InitInstance()` call the `SetWindowPlacement()`